# Django Rest Framework Views in Depth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How to setup the views or serializers in Django Rest Framework to have URLs for depth to add, modify
articles with categories and tags.

```
/api/article/92285/categories
/api/article/92285/tags
```

from following format

```
{
  "article_id": 92285,
  "views": 0,
  "downloads": 0,
  "shares": 0,
  "handle_url": "",
  "title": "Test dataset",
  "defined_type": "dataset",
  "status": "Drafts",
  "published_date": "",
  "description": "Test description",
  "total_size": 0,
  "owner": {
    "id": 13483,
    "full_name": "John  Carter"
  },
  "authors": [
    {
      "first_name": "John ",
      "last_name": "Carter",
      "id": 13483,
      "full_name": "John Carter"
    }
  ],
  "tags": [

  ],
  "categories": [

  ],
  "files": [

  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific.. U need to design nested URLs? May be this is what you are looking for.. https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes